# MPMoviePlayerViewController, remove quicktime symbol/add background image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an MPMoviePlayerViewController that plays audio. I would like to remove the Quicktime logo and/or add a custom background image to the player but keep the playback controls. I swear I have done this before prior to iOS 5 but I can't re-figure it out! Things I have tried:

-Adding a subview to MPMoviePlayerViewController. Puts the subview OVER the playback controls, not good.

-setBackgroundColor of the moviePlayer with a patternimage. Doesn't do anything.

-setView on the entire MPMoviePlayerViewController. As expected, the playback controls and navigation bar are gone. I suppose this could work but I'd need to recreate all the playback controls manually, but I'd really rather not.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the `MPMoviePlayerController` property `backgroundView`.

From the [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html);

> backgroundView
>
> A customizable view that is displayed behind the movie
>   content. (read-only)
>
> @property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *backgroundView
>
> Discussion This
>   view provides the backing content, on top of which the movie content
>   is displayed. You can add subviews to the background view if you want
>   to display custom background content.
>
> This view is part of the view hierarchy returned by the view property.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.2 and later. Declared In
>   MPMoviePlayerController.h

Try something like this (assuming that your instance of the MPMoviePlayerController is called `moviePlayerController`):

```
patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[moviePlayerController.backgroundView addSubview:patternView];
[patternView release];
```

Comment: @Till every question about MPMoviePlayerController will find your name in the answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Till's answer is correct for iPhoneOS 3.  This has changed in iOS 4 and 5.

Apple has now added a readonly property to MPMoviePlayerViewController exposing a MPMovieController.  The MPMovieController has a backgroundView that should be used.

Now you will want to do something like this:

```
patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:patternView];
[patternView release];
```