# MOV on iOS App shows QuickTime Logo At Beginning

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, quicktime

In my app I use, I loop a video over and over again.  It will always show the QuickTime logo at the beginning of the video each time.  I have checked, and there isn't anything like that in the video.  Thoughts to how I can get rid of that?

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"warpspeed" withExtension:@"mov"];
    UIView *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.moviePlayer2.backgroundView addSubview:patternView];
    self.moviePlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [self.moviePlayer2 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    self.moviePlayer2.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer2.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    self.moviePlayer2.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self.moviePlayer2 setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
    self.moviePlayer2.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Quicktime, iOS uses H264 as the only supported movie format on iOS and you cannot do seamless looping with the built-in libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183962/763355

Comment: @MoDJ I know seamless won't work, but it shows the QT logo at the front of the first time it plays the video as well.

Comment: Do you have a link for the movie you're trying to play? Is it fast start (ie. does it have the movie headers at the start of the file, rather than at the end)? If it's not fast start there will be a delay before it loads enough of the movie to show the first frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayerViewController, remove quicktime symbol/add background image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332618/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-remove-quicktime-symbol-add-background-image)